# Python psycopg2 - using .format() with a dbname inside a string

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 to query a database that starts with a number + ".district", so my code goes like:

```
number = 2345

cur = conn.cursor()
myquery = """ SELECT *
              FROM  {0}.districts
              ;""".format(number)

cur.execute("""{0};""".format(query))
data = cur.fetchall()
conn.close()
```

**And i keep receiving the following psycopg2 error..**

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "2345."
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM  2345.districts...

Thought it was the type of data the problem, maybe int(number) or str(number)..but no, same error appears.

¿ What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to use to pass parameters is not supported. Please read [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).